# 400 bad request when using java client to upload file through rest api

Tags: java, rest

I have a requirement where I need to write a rest API to allow upload a file as well as a Java based client to call the API with file information.

Below is the code I have written so far -

```
@POST
    @Path("/uploadFile")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String name = file.getOriginalFilename();
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadLocation + name)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + uploadLocation + name;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
```

Below is the java client i have written -

```
public class TestFileUpload {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/upload/uploadFile");
        httppost.setHeader("content-type", "false");
        File file = new File("C:\\dummyUpload.txt");

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "multipart/form-data");
        mpEntity.addPart("file", cbFile);


        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
          System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
        if (resEntity != null) {
          resEntity.consumeContent();
        }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

However when i start the server, i could see the API running, when i run the client code i am getting 400 bad request.

Any clues, what can be the issue.

Br,

AJ

Comment: What's the HTTP status message? Content-Length header required?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you asked for, below is the message i m getting -

Comment: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
<body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Bad Request</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.30</h3></body></html>

Comment: i don't have any content-length restriction needed, so not required.

Comment: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect", that's the http status message. What is 'content-type' false?

Comment: what should be content-type, avoiding that gives a 415 error.

Comment: It depends on your content type :) see my answer below (the shortest one)

Answer (score 0):

You would typically build a file upload request like so (copied from an [HttpClient example](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/examples/org/apache/http/examples/entity/mime/ClientMultipartFormPost.java)):

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 * ====================================================================
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * <http://www.apache.org/>.
 *
 */
package org.apache.http.examples.entity.mime;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * Example how to use multipart/form encoded POST request.
 */
public class ClientMultipartFormPost {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1)  {
            System.out.println("File path not given");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080" +
                    "/servlets-examples/servlet/RequestInfoExample");

            FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(args[0]));
            StringBody comment = new StringBody("A binary file of some kind", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

            HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .addPart("bin", bin)
                    .addPart("comment", comment)
                    .build();


            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    System.out.println("Response content length: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
                }
                EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }

}
```

The issue is that you are setting `Content-Type` to `false`, which is *not* a valid content type. It seems that it should not be set when using the [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library, and the content type of the `ContentBody` must match the content type of the file you are trying to upload - in this case, it's a text file, so `text/plain` is appropriate.

You also cannot just set the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` - you also have to set a `boundary` property on it, like: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=1234567890ABCDEF`, which is used to separate the files.

EDIT: A controller that could handle it would look like:

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/uploadFile",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
    )
    public String handle(
            @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file
    ) {
        System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
        return "{}";
    }
}
```

Comment: not setting up content-type at all gives 415 error, what do you suggest as value given my controller code, i will be using this controller for loading zip data...any suggestions.

Comment: Not sure, honestly. Which framework are you using for your controller? JAX-RS? Spring?

Comment: I've added an example of a pure Spring controller - I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar enough with Jersey to help you with that, I'm sorry. As far as uploading zip files goes, it would be basically the same, but you'd want to sett the `contentBody` content type to something like `application/zip`.

Answer (score 0):

'Content-Type' header value 'false' is invalid. It should reflect the content type of your data.

For example, if your content body is JSON, then Content-Type header should set with '**application/json**', XML should set with '**application/xml**' etc.. If your content is plain text, you can simply set '**text/plain**'.

You can read on available content types [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type).

Answer (score 0):

Remove header ContentType if you have added any since for form data , no content